Groupby outputting multiple columns
I am trying to output multiple columns from a groupby operation.
My input file is:
enter image description here
Expected output:
enter image description here
The code used:
df = pd.read_csv('testPCI.csv')

output = df.groupby(['Frequency'])['PCI'].count().to_excel("output.xlsx")

And I am getting this:
enter image description here
How can I get the expected output which includes count column as well as % count column.

You can skip groupby and use value_counts -> df.value_counts(normalize=True, ascending=True).mul(100).round(2).reset_index()

Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like code formatting (for print(df)) or table formatting (from print(df.to_markdown()). To aid that, it looks like you can remove the read_csv call and just provide df, as well as remove the .to_excel call and just provide output. See also How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

Here's one approach:
out = (
    pd.concat([
        df.value_counts(sort=False),
        df.value_counts(normalize=True)
          .mul(100)
          .round(2)
          .astype(str) + '%'
    ], axis=1)
    .reset_index()
)

Output:
   Frequency  PCI  count proportion
0        123    5      5     21.74%
1        456    7      8     34.78%
2        999    9     10     43.48%

Explanation

Use df.value_counts with sort=True for 'count'.
Use df.value_counts with normalize=True for 'proportion', with Series.mul + Series.round + Series.astype for the formatting.
Pass both series to pd.concat with axis=1 + df.reset_index.
Chain df.rename if you want to use different column labels.


Try:
(dfc:=df.groupby(['Frequency','PCI'])['PCI'].count().rename('count').reset_index())\
   .assign(count_pct=dfc['count']/dfc['count'].sum()*100).round(2)

Output:
   Frequency  PCI  count  count_pct
0        123    5      5      21.74
1        456    7      8      34.78
2        999    9     10      43.48

Input dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Frequency':[123]*5+[456]*8+[999]*10,
                   'PCI':[5]*5+[7]*8+[9]*10})

Details:
Using the "walrus" operator create a dataframe that counts PCI by Frequency using groupby.   Then use that created dataframe to assign a new column, count_pct as a division of count by the sum of count multiply by 100 and round to two decimal places.

I would use .pipe instead of the walrus: df.(...).pipe(lambda d: d.assign(count_pct=d['count']/d['count']...)

The pipe is easier to read since the logic is more linear. I mean, it goes "do this then this" instead of "save this for later, do this, then use the thing we saved". Also for me, as a rule of thumb, the walrus is a last resort since it can be hard to understand.

@wjandrea: agreed. Though with df.assign, "[i]f the values are callable, they are computed on the DataFrame". I.e., no need for pipe or a walrus ;). I would rewrite it as: df.groupby(['Frequency','PCI'], as_index=False).agg(count=('PCI', 'count')).assign(count_pct=lambda x: (x['count']/x['count'].sum()*100).round(2).astype(str) + '%').
